# TSQL- adding value of every row to the next

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have 2 columns and I want to add the value(hour) of every row to the next row.

```
Date               Hour
2014-01-13 13:00   0
2014-01-13 14:00   3
2014-01-13 16:00   2
```

and  I want to have a new date column that shows like this:

```
Date               Hour      **New_Date**
2014-01-13 13:00   0         2014-01-13 16:00      
2014-01-13 14:00   3         2014-01-13 17:00 
2014-01-13 16:00   2         2014-01-13 18:00
```

Comment: You can most likely do what you are trying to do here using a running total and DATEADD. How you do the running total will depend on which version of sql server you are using. 2012 and 2014 have LEAD and LAG functions which make this pretty simple. 2008 and earlier is a bit more challenging. Search for running total and you will find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT [Date], [Hour],
       DATEADD(hour, (SELECT TOP 1 t2.[Hour]
                      FROM dbo.Tablename t2
                      WHERE t2.[Date] > t1.[Date]
                      ORDER BY t2.[Date]), [Date])
       AS [New_Date]
FROM dbo.TableName t1
ORDER BY [Date]
```

But as you can see in [this sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9032/6/0) the seond row adds two hours since that is the third row's hour. Also, the last row gets no new-date because there is no next-row. Is your desired result wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
     [Date] DATETIME,
     [Hour] INT
  )

INSERT INTO #temp
            ([Date],[Hour])
VALUES      ('2014-01-13 13:00:00',0),
            ('2014-01-13 14:00:00',3),
            ('2014-01-13 16:00:00',2)

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER(
                    ORDER BY [date]) AS id,
                *
         FROM   #temp)
SELECT a.Date,
       a.Hour,
       Dateadd(hh, a.Hour, CASE
                             WHEN a.id != 1 THEN a.[date]
                             ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 date
                                   FROM   cte
                                   ORDER  BY id DESC)
                           END) newdate
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.id = b.id + 1
```

output

```
         Date             Hour             newdate
2014-01-13 13:00:00.000    0        2014-01-13 16:00:00.000
2014-01-13 14:00:00.000    3        2014-01-13 17:00:00.000
2014-01-13 16:00:00.000    2        2014-01-13 18:00:00.000
```